# Model.get(list_of_keys) in a transaction, filtering a single entity group instead of throwing BadRequestError

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a list of keys, which should be children of an entity of MyModel (but some might not be), and I want to get the entities referred to by those keys in a transaction. One way of doing this is:

```
ifilter(None, ModelX.all().ancestor(Y).filter('__key__', xk).get() for xk in xkeys)
```

But it seems inefficient to run a separate query for each key. Is there a way to run IPN.get() on a list of keys in a transaction, preserving order, but ignoring those which don't belong to an entity group, instead of throwing a BadRequestError?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There didn't seem to be a way of doing what I asked, so I returned the keys from the transaction and did an db.get(ks) outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming xkeys is a list of keys

```
results = [db.get(xk) for xk in xkeys]
```

But then, I think you can just do:

```
results = db.get(xkeys)
```

Oh I just read that you said (but some might not be).  This is the problem.  All the entities involved in the transaction must be in the same ancestor group.  So to make this work, you've got to remove the entities that don't have the same ancestor from the list.